# Remove elements from array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

i have an array that the middle part change according to quantity products

```
Array ( [name] => Alberto [email] => email@hotmail.com [code_1] => tshirt [description_1] => Tshirt color red [price_1] => 453.0 [quantity_1] => 1 [subtotal_1] => 453.0 [code_2] => sweater [description_2] => Sweater with long sleeves [price_2] => 23.43 [quantity_2] => 2 [subtotal_2] => 46.86 [employee] => 1 [total] => 499.86 )
```

And i want to remove the first 2 elements and the last 2 elements, just leave

```
Array ( [code_1] => tshirt [description_1] => Tshirt color red [price_1] => 453.0 [quantity_1] => 1 [subtotal_1] => 453.0 [code_2] => sweater [description_2] => Sweater with long sleeves [price_2] => 23.43 [quantity_2] => 2 [subtotal_2] => 46.86 )
```

I try with

```
array_splice($_POST, 2, -2);
```

but this just keep the first 2 and last 2, I need the elements between them.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: When you say remove do you need the data or no? You could simply `unset($array['name']);` and the others if you do not need them

Comment: `$result = array_slice($_POST, 2, count($_POST)-4);` maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slice using `array_slice()` from the 3rd item (offset 2) to the end minus the last 2:

```
$result = array_slice($_POST, 2, -2);
```

Note: If your array is 4 items or less obviously,  you won't get anything.

To do it with `array_splice()`, remove the first 2 and then the last 2:

```
array_splice($_POST, 0, 2);
array_splice($_POST, -2);
```

Since this is an associative array it may be better to get only the keys that you want regardless of order:

```
$wanted = array('price_1', 'quantity_1'); // etc...
$result = array_intersect_key($_POST, array_flip($wanted));
```

Comment: Actually this works great, thanks a lot AbraCadaver :)

Comment: You can just provide `-2` for the length argument of array_slice to count backwards from the end instead of length-4.

Comment: Since i know the part that sorrund the products also this method works: unset($_POST['name']); unset($_POST['email']); unset($_POST['employee']); unset($_POST['total']);

Comment: Added an alternative since you should know what keys you want.

Comment: array_slice function may surprise you if you use arbitrary numeric values for keys, i.e. – no excuses and benefits from using error prone function like array_slice.

Answer (score 0):

**Since your data structure is a HASH MAP you SHOULD NOT remove the elements with numeric indexes (key position).**

It is a HASH MAP and you MUST NOT relay on indexes (key position), RELAY only on keys.

Remove any element from an array (hash map) using `unset` instruction.

```
unset($arr['name'], $arr('email'));
```

Comment: There are `array_slice` and `array_splice` functions that allow for removing elements from an array by numeric index regardless of keys.

Comment: I added probably a better way, since I hope OP knows which keys they want.